# ruby regex for removing url prefix and ending

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been trying to figure this out, and i've searched but I'm stuck.

Lets say I have the string www.google.com or http://google.com or just google.com

and I want to extract the string **google** out of those parameters.

A solution I can think of is first removing the first parameters (www.) then removing the second section of the string (.com) but I know there is a similar more efficient way.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're going to have a hard time using a single (or multiple) regex for this. URLs aren't that simple, and, besides the domain, can have a country code, plus multiple host designations (`http://www.open.gov.uk` for instance). See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 to get an idea what you're up against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, start with a tool designed to work with URLs. Ruby includes [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), and there's also [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable).

Using these you can strip down a URI into its defined components:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html')
uri.host # => "www.ruby-doc.org"
```

If your string doesn't start with a scheme, you can add one. (Schemes are important.)

```
url = 'foo.bar.com/some/path'
URI.parse('http://' + url).host
# => "foo.bar.com"
```

From that point you're going to have a tough time determining what is the true host, versus the domain. A domain can be anything (pretty much) and the host can be the domain name. Possibly you can get a list of domains but, remember that the list is constantly changing.

[ICANN](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) has a list of TLDs, as does [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db). Those are ONLY the top-level-domains, not the hosts that sit under them. However, using those lists you can strip the TLD from a host, and at least be a tiny bit closer to where you want to be.

Comment: I think you're right and this is the only reliable way of doing this, I realised how futile my attempts at a regex were so deleted the answer.

Comment: You're right, there are multiple cases that a simple regex cannot match properly. This makes sense and I will follow up and read more about this scheme. Thanks a bunch!